# Add image from database on digital signature acrofield in with contains of digital signature PDF using ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#

I have a signature pad. I saved signature pad value as byte array image in database. I have displayed this image on image control. I wanted to display same image on Digital Signature control in Pdf.
To display content on pdf I have used class file in my project.

Below I have attached code to display it:

```
public String Signature
{
    get
    {
        //if employee has not agreed to the Electronic Signature form - do not place signature on form.
        EmployeePortal.Models.NCI.NCIEntities ent = EmployeePortal.Models.ClsNCIUtil.GetNCIEntity(custid);
        using (ent)
        {
            EmployeePortal.Models.NCI.EmployeeSignature empSignature = ent.EmployeeSignatures.OrderByDescending(a => a.SignID).FirstOrDefault(a => a.EmployeeId == employee.EmployeeId);
            EmployeePortal.Models.NCI.EmployeeOnboarding empsign = ent.EmployeeOnboardings.FirstOrDefault(a => a.EmployeeId == employee.EmployeeId);
 
            if (empsign == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (empsign.IAgree == true)
            {
                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding(); 
                return encoding.GetString(empSignature.SignatureFile);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

How can I display image on digital signature acrofield?

Comment: What errors are you facing? And please keep your question to the essentials by including the problem + what you have tried. No need to specify your deadlines and wishes.

Comment: i am not getting any error image is not getting display on digital signature acrofield